# angular ui bootstrap typehead not selected on click mouse

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typehead

When I us a mouseClickListener on an item it is not selected. No error is issued, however it is working when I press on Enter.

"angular": "1.5.8","angular-animate": "1.5.8","angular-touch": "1.5.8"

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nomeItensBusca" placeholder="Busca de Itens" uib-typeahead="item as item.nome for item in getItemURLAsync($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingItem" typeahead-no-results="noResultsItem" typeahead-on-select="itemSelecionadoF($model); nomeItensBusca='';" class="form-control"/>
```

[thypehead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sucp.png)

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Can you please provide the code in plnkr.co? Need more information.

Comment: No error is issued, only works with enter